# How to link my C++/CLI (managed) developed in VC++ 9 with CLR support static library to my native code(Application) in VC++ 6.0?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

It is quite urgent, I do want to link a static library that has been written  in **C++/CLI** managed code syntax with CLR support to my native code (application) written in C using **VC++ 6.0.** How should I do?
Would be it possible ? Does Linker of VC++ 6.0 support l managed library inking? Please suggest all solution to this problem?

Comment: So your final application will be a native one or managed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I managed to do it in spite of

"The following list outlines the recommended hardware, software, network infrastructure, and service packs that you need:

```
Visual C# .NET or Visual C# 2005
Visual C++ .NET or Visual C++ 2005"
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your response but here I am talking about static library(.lib not .dll) that get linked at compiled time.